# Terminal shows "launchctl usage: setenv <key> <value>" on top of every session

Tags: bash, osx-lion

Every time I open a Terminal window the following is printed on the top:

```
launchctl usage: setenv <key> <value>
```

I figured something must be wrong with my `.bash_profile` but I could not find anything in there related to "Daemons/Services".

What else could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message appears every time you open a terminal, there is probably a problem in one of `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`. You are probably calling `launchctl` with wrong parameters. Try searching for the relevant line:

```
grep launchctl ~/.bash_profile /etc/profile ~/.profile ~/bash_login
```

That should show you which file is calling `launchctl` and you can then either remove the offending line or correct it.

`bash` only reads `~/bash_profile` and `/etc/profile` when launched as a login shell. In OS X, when you open a new terminal, this is the case, whereas in most (if not all) other *nix terminals, an interactive, non-login shell is launched and `~/.bashrc` is read instead. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/585699/151431) for more info.

Comment: OS X always launches a login shell from the Terminal. See http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: @slhck Oh! Thanks, did not know that, will update answer accordingly.

Comment: I rewrote your answer a little so it makes more sense when looking at it from an OS X perspective. Since `launchctl` is exclusive to OS X I think it's easy enough to focus this on OS X and mention the difference to Linux at the end. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @slhck not in the least, thanks. Any particular reason you removed `~/bash_login`? Does that not exist on OSX?

Comment: Sorry, I must've missed that. A rather uncommon file, but for the sake of completeness, this and `~/.profile` could of course be mentioned.

Comment: @slhck I agree it is not that common but since I had included both files in my original answer your edit just made me wonder if they were absent from OSX.